# How to change text color in output from enscript

Tags: linux, macos, enscript

I am am converting simple text file to PDF from command line on Mac using following code:

```
enscript -Bp '-' input.txt | pstopdf -i -o outfile.pdf
```

What I would like to do is that color my text/font in PDF file. I believe enscript has color options but I could not make it work. For example, how can I convert a text in input.txt into red fonts. Can anyone help? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a thread that has the answer.

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/use-of-special-escapes-with-enscript-164978/

In short first define escape character as follow: -e~ (tilda is escape character in this case).

Now, make sure that escape is in your input.txt file:
~color{1 0 0}This is a sentence in input file.

When you run the command input file text should be colored in red.